# Will Postgres not start if disc space on database server is full?

Tags: database, postgresql, space, mount

My Postgresql database stopped working, which has shut down all of my Django applications that use it. I tried restarting with 'service postgresql restart', but it gives me this response

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                                                                                                     
* The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output.
```

I checked the logs at /var/log/postgresql, but the most recent logs file has nothing in it. I checked the one before that, and I don't think anything in particular besides a lot of errors that say there is no disc space.

**/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log.1**

```
2018-03-15 08:46:09 CDT LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_12061.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-15 08:46:09 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-15 08:46:09 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-15 08:46:10 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-15 08:46:10 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-15 08:46:15 CDT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/616778.1": No space left on device
2018-03-15 08:46:15 CDT HINT:  Check free disk space.
2018-03-15 08:46:15 CDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "vehicle_vehicleimage" ("vehicle_id", "image_url", "display_sequence") VALUES (1606764, 'https://content.homenetiol.com/2001722/2120878/640x480/43d0a25930554cdbbbd0834c9803e5ad.jpg', 1) RET$
2018-03-15 08:46:19 CDT LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-03-15 08:46:20 CDT LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-03-16 08:45:49 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-16 08:45:49 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-16 08:45:53 CDT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/616778.1": No space left on device
2018-03-16 08:45:53 CDT HINT:  Check free disk space.
2018-03-16 08:45:53 CDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "vehicle_vehicleimage" ("vehicle_id", "image_url", "display_sequence") VALUES (1587463, 'https://content.homenetiol.com/2001722/2120878/640x480/c80fb80f8dc04c2581872ad2cf221cbc.jpg', 1) RET$
2018-03-16 08:45:59 CDT LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-03-17 08:45:48 CDT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/616778.1": No space left on device
2018-03-17 08:45:48 CDT HINT:  Check free disk space.
2018-03-17 08:45:48 CDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "vehicle_vehicleimage" ("vehicle_id", "image_url", "display_sequence") VALUES (1144699, 'https://content.homenetiol.com/2001722/2120878/640x480/4e7711dd0d5148eeaadd1e8a7f00b0eb.jpg', 1) RET$
2018-03-18 08:45:44 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-18 08:45:44 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-18 08:45:47 CDT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/616778.1": No space left on device
2018-03-18 08:45:47 CDT HINT:  Check free disk space.
2018-03-18 08:45:47 CDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "vehicle_vehicleimage" ("vehicle_id", "image_url", "display_sequence") VALUES (1144694, 'https://content.homenetiol.com/2001722/2120878/640x480/3dee837dd31942c5a26bc73775f07dba.jpg', 0) RET$
2018-03-18 08:45:54 CDT LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-03-18 10:21:40 CDT FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "socialauto"
2018-03-18 10:21:40 CDT DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 17: "local   all             all                                     md5"
2018-03-15 08:46:15 CDT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/616778.1": No space left on device
2018-03-15 08:46:15 CDT HINT:  Check free disk space.
2018-03-15 08:46:15 CDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "vehicle_vehicleimage" ("vehicle_id", "image_url", "display_sequence") VALUES (1606764, 'https://content.homenetiol.com/2001722/2120878/640x480/43d0a25930554cdbbbd0834c9803e5ad.jpg', 1) RET$
2018-03-15 08:46:19 CDT LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-03-15 08:46:20 CDT LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-03-16 08:45:49 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-16 08:45:49 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-16 08:45:53 CDT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/616778.1": No space left on device
2018-03-16 08:45:53 CDT HINT:  Check free disk space.
2018-03-16 08:45:53 CDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "vehicle_vehicleimage" ("vehicle_id", "image_url", "display_sequence") VALUES (1587463, 'https://content.homenetiol.com/2001722/2120878/640x480/c80fb80f8dc04c2581872ad2cf221cbc.jpg', 1) RET$
2018-03-16 08:45:59 CDT LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-03-17 08:45:48 CDT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/616778.1": No space left on device
2018-03-17 08:45:48 CDT HINT:  Check free disk space.
2018-03-17 08:45:48 CDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "vehicle_vehicleimage" ("vehicle_id", "image_url", "display_sequence") VALUES (1144699, 'https://content.homenetiol.com/2001722/2120878/640x480/4e7711dd0d5148eeaadd1e8a7f00b0eb.jpg', 1) RET$
2018-03-18 08:45:44 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-18 08:45:44 CDT LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat_tmp/global.tmp": No space left on device
2018-03-18 08:45:47 CDT ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/616778.1": No space left on device
2018-03-18 08:45:47 CDT HINT:  Check free disk space.
2018-03-18 08:45:47 CDT STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "vehicle_vehicleimage" ("vehicle_id", "image_url", "display_sequence") VALUES (1144694, 'https://content.homenetiol.com/2001722/2120878/640x480/3dee837dd31942c5a26bc73775f07dba.jpg', 0) RET$
2018-03-18 08:45:54 CDT LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
2018-03-18 10:21:40 CDT FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "socialauto"
```

I checked the disc space on the virtual machine hosting the database with the 'df' command, and it does indeed look like all the space has been used up

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       49300032 49283648         0 100% /
devtmpfs         2014088        4   2014084   1% /dev
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none              403388      340    403048   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2016924        0   2016924   0% /run/shm
none              102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
```

I also get this weird message whenever I try to autocomplete a path with tab

```
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

Is the only way to get Postgres up and running to increase the disc space on my machine. Is there any way to use **'service postgresql restart'** with some debug flag to see the error its facing without having to go into a log file ?

Comment: Instead of increasing the disk space, you can clean up your filesystem - there is likely a lot of temp files, old log fiels etc. that you don't need that can free up some space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `strace` the server process ...

But seriously — if you are out of space, that is the reason. If PostgreSQL cannot allocate a new transaction log, it will refuse to start.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest would be starting the postgres and tailing the log, smth like

```
tail -f ${PGDATA}/postgresql-$(date --iso-8601)* | grep "ERROR\|FATAL"
```

or whatever your log looks like.

And surely you can't run database without free space. As you mentioned yourself you can't even use bash autocompletion.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect the database to operate if the disk is full? Where is new data stored, or logs, or transaction logs?

Why don't you start by cleaning up disk space. Find out what is using disk space, and remove what is unnecessary. Uninstall packages you don't need, clean up old logfiles in /var/log, or temporary files in /tmp or /var/tmp.

And please do not delete PostgreSQL WAL files!